# dense_rank in sql partition by id and session id but ordered by timestamp

Tags: sql, hive, hql, rank, dense-rank

I have a table as following:

| User ID | Session ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 7e938c4437a0 | 1:30:30 |
| 100 | 7e938c4437a0 | 1:30:33 |
| 100 | c1fcfd8b1a25 | 2:40:00 |
| 100 | 7b5e86d91103 | 3:20:00 |
| 200 | bda6c8743671 | 2:20:00 |
| 200 | bda6c8743671 | 2:25:00 |
| 200 | aac5d66421a0 | 3:10:00 |
| 200 | aac5d66421a0 | 3:11:00 |

I am trying to rank each session_id for by user_id, sequenced(ordered by) timestamp. I want something like the second table.

I am doing the following but it does not order by timestamp:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by session_id) as visit_number
```

it outputs in wrong order and when I add timestamp in the order by it behaves like a row_number() function.

Below is what I am really looking for to get as a result:

| User ID | Session ID | Timestamp | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 7e938c4437a0 | 1:30:30 | 1 |
| 100 | 7e938c4437a0 | 1:30:33 | 1 |
| 100 | c1fcfd8b1a25 | 2:40:00 | 2 |
| 100 | 7b5e86d91103 | 3:20:00 | 3 |
| 200 | bda6c8743671 | 2:20:00 | 1 |
| 200 | bda6c8743671 | 2:25:00 | 1 |
| 200 | aac5d66421a0 | 3:10:00 | 2 |
| 200 | aac5d66421a0 | 3:11:00 | 2 |

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Please describe the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dense rank by the *hour* component of the timestamp, you can extract the hour.  This should give the results you specify.  In standard SQL, this looks like:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by extract(hour from timestamp) as visit_number
```

Of course, date/time functions are highly database dependent, so your database might have a different function for extracting the hour.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The session_id comes from the source and is based on a 30min cut-off time. Extracting hour would not work in this case since each session is 30 mins, and also the duration of a session could overlap in 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and since I found the answer I thought I would come and post here. This is what I have learned you can do.

```
SELECT user_id, session_id, session_timestamp,
    -- This ranks the records according to the date, which is the same for each user_id, session_group
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.user_id  ORDER BY tbl.min_dt) AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, session_id, session_timestamp,
        -- We want to get the MIN or MAX session_timestamp but only for each group. This allows us to keep the ordering by timestamp, but still group by user_id and session_id.
        MIN(session_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id) AS min_dt
    FROM sessions) tbl
ORDER BY user_id, rank, session_timestamp
```

This is the results that look the same as asked for.

[image: Query Results]